# How to I store API response in Array?

Tags: angular

I have created a angular application which creates several forms dynamically by reading JSON as shown below

```
{
"controls": [
    {
      "name": "Country",
      "label": "Country",
      "controlType": "picklist"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pincode",
      "label": "Pincode",
      "controlType": "number"
    },
    {
      "name": "EmployeeID",
      "label": "EmployeeID",
      "controlType": "picklist"
    }
}
```

For the control type picklist, i want to read the values from API and bind it with dropdown controls. I want to know what is the best way to subscribe to APIs and store these values somewhere so that when the form loads, it will just bind the values to the control

I have the service written where it calls the API

```
*ngFor="let control of formControls; let i = index"
......
.....
if (control.controlType == 'picklist'){
            <mat-form-field
              appearance="outline"
            >
              <mat-select [formControlName]="control.name">
                @for(item of ArrayList[i]; track item){
                <mat-option [value]="item.id">{{ item.cohortName }}</mat-option>
                }
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

I have written a reference service, which calls the individual services to get values. But this is not dynamic as of now

```
export class ReferenceService {
  CountryList: any;
  StudentList: any;

  constructor(
    private countryService: CountryService,
    private studentService: StudentService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.countryService.CountryList.subscribe((res) => {
      this.CountryList= of(res);
    });

    this.studentService.StudentList.subscribe((res) => {
      this.StudentList= of(res);
    });
  }

  GetList(name: string) {
    switch (name.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'country': {
        return this.CountryList;
      }
      case 'studentID': {
        return this.StudentList;
      }
    }
  }
```